# Finite arrangement of infinite sums or products

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, infinite-product

Infinite sum and product changes value under (infinite) arrangement of the terms, if the sum or product exists. I was wondering what happens if I only swap a finite number of terms in the sum / product. My guess is that the value shouldn't change in this case.

Answer (score 1):

An [absolutely convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence) infinite sum will not change value under rearrangement.  A conditionally convergent sum that is not absolutely convergent can be made to sum to any number by the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).  For products you can just take the logs and use the sum theorems.

Yes, if you change the order of a finite number of terms it will not matter.  There is a last term changed.  The sum or product out to there will be the same by commutativity and associativity, then the rest is the same.

Comment: What about divergent sums? If there is a sensible assignment of finite value to a divergent sum, is this value preserved under finite rearrangement of terms?

Comment: A finite rearrangement will not change a divergent sum to a convergent one by the same reasoning as my second paragraph.  I would argue that there is no sensible assignment of a finite value to a divergent sum, so the answer to your question would be yes as the antecedent is false.  Are you thinking of $1+2+3+4+5+\ldots = -\frac 1{12}?$  I don't know how one arrives at that, so I don't know if it is preserved.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of zeta function and family of such functions. I'm also thinking of Ramanujan sum and similar kind of stuff